# Symfony Custom Events

Tags: symfony, events

In my project, I have multiple entities that need some lifecyclecallback like functions. I say 'lifecyclecallback like' because I want to update some other entites and I feel like using an Entity Listener or Subscriber to update parent or child entities is bad practice. So I thought that Events might be the best thing to use.

For example, I have a `Post` Entity that is related to `Topic` via many to one. When creating a new `Post`, I want to dispatch an event for that, when updating, I want to create an Event for that etc... At first I thought I could create a PostEvent class that contains all of these Events but the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) suggest creating a seperate class for each event. So in my case, I would have something like

- PostCreateEvent
- PostEditEvent
- PostRemoveEvent
- etc...

This seems really tedious to me, I'd end up with a bunch of files and classes that have a similar purpose. I've noticed that FosUserBundle provides some similar functionality, but I don't understand what is happening.
Am I doing this wrong and is there a better way to dispatch these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different events (PostCreateEvent, PostEditEvent etc) is good if you want create your solution as bundle for later use. If it only part of specific application, I think will be enough just make some handler where you make business logic. You can call this handler from controller.

Answer (score 1):

Different events hold different values.

For instance, I can imagine `PostCreatedEvent` to hold the initial values the post was created with, `PostEditedEvent` would hold the diff and `PostDeletedEvent` only holds the ID of the deleted post.

If they hold similar values (please think twice about this!), you can combine them into one event class. Please note that this all is up to you, the EventDispatcher component doesn't care at all.

As a small tip, if you want to do some *action* instead of just *notifying* the outside world that something happend, consider using Commands and a Command Bus instead. See for instance [these blogposts](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2015/01/a-wave-of-command-buses/) by the author of SimpleBus.